# display json data in html

Tags: jquery, html, json

What is the best way to display json information in html, I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

My code

```html
  $.getJSON('example.json', function(data) {
         var html = '';
         $.each(data.example, function(key, value) {

   html += '<p> Name:' + value.name + '</p>';

   html += '<p> Email:' + value.email + '</p>'

               });

       $('#example').append(html);
    });
});
```

My json

```html
{
    "example": [
        {
          "name": "Dr. Sammie Boyer",
          "email": "Lavonne.Kiehn@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Eladio Beier",
          "email": "Lavonne.Kiehn@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Hilton Borer",
          "email": "Reva.Goyette@yahoo.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: maybe `$.each(data.example`

Comment: if you put `console.log()` inside the loop e.g `console.log(value.name);` or `console.log(value);` what are you getting?

Comment: the console print everything from the json file but it still doesn't display in the html

Answer (score 0):

It's always helpful to `console.log` things you're trying to debug, if you do run a `console.log` on `data` you'll see that there's nothing called `contacts` since it's called `example` in the JSON-file, try changing either `example` -> `contacts` in the JSON or `contacts` -> `example` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check this it could help you.

```js
var data = {
    "example": [
        {
          "name": "Dr. Sammie Boyer",
          "email": "Lavonne.Kiehn@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Eladio Beier",
          "email": "Lavonne.Kiehn@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Hilton Borer",
          "email": "Reva.Goyette@yahoo.com"
        }
    ]
};
         var html = '';
         $.each(data.example, function(key, value) {

   html += '<p> Name:' + value.name + '</p>';

   html += '<p> Email:' + value.email + '</p>'

               });

       $('#example').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"> </div>
```